# What are all the options when instantiating a Flask-SQLAlchemy Column?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm starting a Flask project and I'm using [Flask-SQLAlchemy](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/). When I instantiate a model, I get to pick certain parameters in `db.Column` like `primary_key`, `index`, `unique`:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
```

I looked at the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html) but I couldn't find a clear list of every option and their respective functionality.

**What parameters can I use in `db.Column` and what exactly do they do?**

Comment: You want the [Column] documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are listed [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#column-table-metadata-api), under **Column, Table, MetaData API**.

For example, [`primary_key`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.primary_key) is documented as

> **primary_key** – If `True`, marks this column as a primary key column. Multiple columns can have this flag set to specify composite primary keys. As an alternative, the primary key of a Table can be specified via an explicit PrimaryKeyConstraint object.